# How to know when a picture is being selected in Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA (1 month), and I can't find how to get my code to know when I select a picture in Excel.

I want to be able to autoselect the cell containing the picture if I select the picture instead of the cell.

The picture already has the same name as the cell with "INV" as start (ex: `INV$A$1`).

The code must also work for double clicks, as double clicking the cell triggers some subroutine.

Everything is already written, but if I click the picture rather than the cell, nothing  happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a macro to your images when they're inserted. You can use the same macro for all images and check the value of `Application.Caller` to determine which image/shape was clicked.

```
Sub Pics_Clicks()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Great. I used this as a basis , and all is fine. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    MsgBox "clicked via Click!"
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_GotFocus()
    MsgBox "clicked via GotFocus!"
End Sub
```

Here, "Image1" is the automatically created name of a control of type `Image`.
Such a control is inserted to an `Excel` sheet in `Design Mode`. Double click on the control to get the event handler routine auto-edited in the `VBA` editor.