# Can Worksheet_SelectionChange() trigger upon selection of a picture or image? in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image, selection

I would like to trigger a macro upon selection of an image. Can Worksheet_SelectionChange() do this? It seems to require a range which I don't think an image would count. So how else can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717531/how-to-know-when-a-picture-is-being-selected-in-excel-with-vba. The long and the short of it is that Shapes' (images are Shapes) click event links to a macro that must be specified.

Answer (score 1):

So no, Worksheet_SelectionChange()doesn't work, but you can go into "Design Mode" then right click on the shape/picture and select "Assign macro". That macro will activate every time you click on the shape, unless you are in "Design mode".